# Rails 3, JRuby and Warbler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, warbler

I am trying to deploy a Rails 3 application on Tomcat 6.0.24. The JRuby version is 1.6.2 (ruby-1.8.7-p330) and Warbler is 1.3.0. I use bundler to handle the gem dependencies.

Checked the WEB-INF/lib folder and the following jars are present:

- jruby-rack-1.0.9.jar
- jruby-core-1.6.2.jar
- jruby-stdlib-1.6.2.jar

But, however after the server starts, hitting the application results in the following exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.kenai.jaffl.struct.Struct$Constants
    com.kenai.jaffl.struct.Struct$Signed64.<init>(Struct.java:1074)
    org.jruby.ext.posix.HeapStruct$Int64.<init>(HeapStruct.java:41)
    org.jruby.ext.posix.LinuxHeapFileStat.<init>(LinuxHeapFileStat.java:35)
    org.jruby.ext.posix.LinuxPOSIX.allocateStat(LinuxPOSIX.java:26)
    org.jruby.ext.posix.LinuxPOSIX.stat(LinuxPOSIX.java:107)
    org.jruby.ext.posix.LazyPOSIX.stat(LazyPOSIX.java:226)
    org.jruby.RubyFileTest.directory_p(RubyFileTest.java:102)
    org.jruby.RubyFileTest.directory_p(RubyFileTest.java:87)
    org.jruby.RubyFileTest$FileTestFileMethods.directory_p(RubyFileTest.java:428)
    org.jruby.RubyFileTest$FileTestFileMethods$s$1$0$directory_p.call(RubyFileTest$FileTestFileMethods$s$1$0$directory_p.gen:65535)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:282)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:139)
    org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:111)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:147)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:163)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:262)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:105)
    org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgNode.interpret(CallNoArgNode.java:63)
    org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:117)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104)
    org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:120)
    org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:145)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.cacheAndCall(SuperCallSite.java:286)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.callBlock(SuperCallSite.java:70)
    org.jruby.runtime.callsite.SuperCallSite.call(SuperCallSite.java:75)
    org.jruby.ast.ZSuperNode.interpret(ZSuperNode.java:101)
    org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:104).....
```

Does that ring any bells?

[Answer Updated]: The issue was with the java implementation on the server. It was Open JDK.  I switched it over to Sun Java 1.6.0_26 and everything started working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the java implementation on the server. It was Open JDK. I switched it over to Sun Java 1.6.0_26 and everything started working

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a new bug or an old one. Consider googling the error or looking on http://bugs.jruby.org.

You might try setting `-Djruby.native.enabled=false` in the VM to use the pure-Java POSIX layer and avoid this error.